# Fourier transformation of $f(2t), \; f(2t+1), \; f(2t+1)e^{it}$, etc if $\mathcal{F}[f](t)$ is known

Tags: fourier-transform

Suppose that a function$\,$ $f(t)$ $\,$has the Fourier transform 
$\,$$\hat f(\omega)=e^{-\omega^4}$.
What general rules are there for computing the Fourier transforms of things like $\,$$g(t)=f(2t)$, $\,$ $h(t)=f(2t+1)$, $k(t)=f(2t+1)e^{it}$ and similar?

I know that the Fourier transforms are the once below and I know how to find them (by finding f(t) by the inverse transform and then transforming f(2t+1) etc.)
My question is if there is a quicker way of finding a Fourier transform of a function with a modified argument if the transform of the function is known.(?)

$$\hat g (\omega)=\frac{1}{2} \hat f \left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\omega^4}{16}}$$

$$\hat h (\omega)=e^{i \frac{\omega}{2}} \hat g (\omega) = 
\frac{1}{2}e^{i \frac{\omega}{2}-\frac{\omega^4}{16}}$$

$$\hat k (\omega)= \hat h (\omega-1)=\frac{1}{2}e^{i \frac{(\omega-1)}{2}-\frac{(\omega-1)^4}{16}}$$

Comment: Are you asking for proofs of these identities, in other words? If so, to recollection, they follow straight from the definition of the Fourier transform and its inverse (the integral and such).

Comment: No, I am not looking for proofs. I know how to calculate them by finding f(t) by the inverse transform and then transforming f(2t+1) etc. My question is if there is a quicker way of finding a Fourier transform of a function with a modified argument if the transform of the function Is known. I should have written my question clearer. @EeveeTrainer

Comment: So do you mean a more general rule, like the laws themselves? Like how to find $f(\gamma t)$ where $\gamma$ is any constant, not necessarily $2$ (as in your definition for $g$)?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Exactly!, and $f(2\gamma+ 1)$ and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed such laws!

Throughout, we will consider ourselves with a function $f(t)$ and its Fourier transform, and we will let $\gamma$ be a real constant.

We will also suppose $f$ has a defined transform and inverse transform where needed, denoted  $\mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_\omega$ and  $\mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\omega)] \right|_t$ respectively.

> (Generally speaking I'm borrowing naming and notation conventions from my own textbook/lectures on the topic from this semester if the sudden change in such confuses you. I also modify these slightly so that they make slightly more sense or are at least easier to remember. I find them a lot nicer to work with than what you presented, no offense intended.)

---

**Scalar Laws:** *(we further assume $\gamma \neq 0$ here)*

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [f(\gamma t)] \right|_\omega = \frac{1}{|\gamma |} \mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_\omega$$

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\gamma \omega)] \right|_t = \frac{1}{|\gamma |} \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\omega)] \right|_t$$

---

**Translation Laws:**

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [f(t - \gamma )] \right|_\omega = e^{-i2\pi \gamma \omega} \cdot \mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_\omega$$

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\omega - \gamma )] \right|_t = e^{i2\pi \gamma \omega} \cdot \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\omega)] \right|_t$$

Equivalently, following directly from these, one can also state,

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [e^{i2\pi \gamma \omega} \cdot f(t)] \right|_\omega = \mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_{\omega - \gamma}$$

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [e^{-i2\pi \gamma \omega} \cdot f(\omega)] \right|_t = \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left. [f(\omega)] \right|_{t - \gamma }$$

---

You can utilize these as necessary to manipulate your function into a "nicer" place. You might need to utilize multiple identities in sequence

For example, in finding the transform of $f(2t+1)$, you'd first want to note that $f(2t+1)=f(2(t+\frac{1}{2}))$. Then you can apply a translation identity with $\gamma = -\frac{1}{2}$, which gives you an $e^{(stuff)}$ factor times the transform of $f(2t)$. Then you apply the scaling identity to get a constant times the transform of $f(t)$.

Or, to just show the calculation, first we use the translation identity:

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [f(2t+1)] \right|_\omega = \mathscr{F} \left. \left[ f \left( 2 \left( t+\frac{1}{2} \right) \right)  \right] \right|_\omega = e^{-i2\pi \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \omega} \cdot \mathscr{F} \left. [f(2t)] \right|_\omega = e^{i\pi \omega}  \cdot \mathscr{F} \left. [f(2t)] \right|_\omega$$

Then we use the scaling identity on the transform we got:

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [f(2t)] \right|_\omega = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_\omega$$

Thus, overall,

$$\mathscr{F} \left. [f(2t+1)] \right|_\omega = \frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{i\pi \omega}  \cdot \mathscr{F} \left. [f(t)] \right|_\omega$$

---

> I'll be the first to admit that it's entirely likely I made minor mistakes in the preceding statements of the identities/calculations. This was a mess to look at the LaTeX for and while I think everything checks out I could be completely wrong. Still, worst case, you could Google up "Fourier transform scalar translation identities" and pull up some results - or maybe even look in the index of your own text, OP, if you have one. I'd be surprised if a text didn't cover these identities. But yes, long story short, there are identities to cover cases such as those in the original post.